# Forced Password change in PasswordRecovery control

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am using Password Recovery Control in asp.net. This control is sending email to the user with his password, but i want to force him to change the password when he login again.

If you know please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This should help you http://forums.asp.net/post/2414936.aspx - I have done something similar and works well.